# Ag-Grid: get Quickfilter text

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In ag-grid with Angular, I need to get the current Quickfilter text. When I check the value of `gridOptions.quickFilterText`, it's *undefined* and the ts definition shows it as deprecated.

Is there an API that exposes the Quickfilter text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register `onFilterChanged: onFilterChanged` in `gridOptions`

```
function onFilterChanged(params){
  console.log(params.api.columnController.gridApi.filterManager.quickFilter);
}
```

Hope this helps!